# addSubview can not correctly show all the content in the viewController?

Tags: ios, addsubview, uicontainerview, presentviewcontroller

In my case, my view hierarchy:

```
UIViewController
      View
        container view + button
          (in container view)  tableview
```

[image]

I want to present this view controller as left slide menu

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SlideMenu", bundle: nil)
    let leftSlideMenu = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftSlideMenu") as! LeftSlideMenu
    leftSlideMenu.view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, 100, view.superview!.frame.size.height)
 // this line is set the slide menu to right frame to only take a part of screen and looks like a "Slide Menu"
    presentViewController(leftSlideMenu, animated: false, completion: nil)
// this is good and show all content in the view controller but the frame is not in control
```

[image]

When I use this, it only show button but not show table view

```
view.addSubview(leftSlideMenu.view)
```

[image]

Comment: do you have any demo ? still i can't understand what you are doing ?

Comment: what is the meaning of this line ?     leftSlideMenu.view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, 100, view.superview!.frame.size.height)

Comment: i write this in my project and it's hard to give all the code. I want to use the view controller "left slide menu" to present as a slide menu, so I try to set the left slide menu's frame